# Count certain values based on criteria and for latest perio

Tags: powerbi, dax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJtvh.png)

I want distinctcount of [Emp Name] from table2 with [Leaving] = "Yes" and their latest status in Table1 is "T". Both the tables are connected with calendar table using date columns and are interconnected with inactive relationship using composite key of EmpID + month-year